# How to get value of selected checkbox?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

Here is my code running from change event of the checkbox,

```
var ch:CheckBox = event.currentTarget as CheckBox;
Alert.show(ch.data.toString())
```

But unable to get selected checkbox value. It's returning [Object][Object]. Even I tried valueOf() but no success.

What am I missing ?

Comment: It's fixed. There was a problem in binding..

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
ch.selected;
```